# How to combine pairs of items from a Vec in a way that consumes the second?

Tags: rust, vector, borrow-checker

I got a typical borrow checker error and I hope people could show me some idiomatic solution. Below please see a miniature example.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Cell {
    ploidy: u32,
}

impl Cell {
    fn from_ploidy(ploidy: u32) -> Self {
        Cell { ploidy }
    }
    
    fn hybrid(&mut self, cell: Cell) { // I would like `cell` to be consumed.
        self.ploidy += cell.ploidy;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cells = vec![
        Cell::from_ploidy(46), Cell::from_ploidy(40), 
        Cell::from_ploidy(46), Cell::from_ploidy(40)
        ];
    println!("{:?}", cells);

    // To hybrid every two consecutive cells
    // e.g. cells[0].hybrid(cells[1]); 
    //      cells[2].hybrid(cells[3]);
    // and let go cells[1] and cells[3]
    for i in 0..2usize {
        cells[i*2].hybrid(cells[i*2+1]);
    }
    println!("{:?}", cells);
}
```

The error is

```
cannot borrow `cells` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
immutable borrow occurs here
```

Basically I would like the resources of `cells[1]`, `cells[3]` to be moved into `cells[0]`, `cells[2]` while `cells[1]`, `cells[3]` themselves to be freed from `cells`.

Comment: You cannot move out of an array. Is `Cell` `Copy`?

Comment: It is not `Copy` @Chayim Friedman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `Vec` and merged cells aren't necessarily adjacent, then you have some complications. You can't just pull values out of any index since `Vec`s' elements must always be contiguous. Either remedy of shifting elements in or using `swap_remove` to fill from the end you have an issue of your indexes for your pairs no-longer being stable.

Fear not though, there are ways to order things how we like. It would be ideal to order the cells such that the ones being consumed will be at the end and the corresponding ones being merged into at the beginning such that `cells[idx]` can just merge with the one from `cells.pop()` (thus the ones at the end should be in reverse order).

We can create this ordering by using the code from my answer here [How to sort (reorder) a Vec by indices?](/a/69774341/2189130) and create the sort order like so:

```
let mut cells = vec![
    Cell::from_ploidy(0), Cell::from_ploidy(1), 
    Cell::from_ploidy(2), Cell::from_ploidy(3),
    Cell::from_ploidy(4), Cell::from_ploidy(5),
];

let pairs = vec![(1, 5), (0, 3), (4, 2)];

let sort_indicies = Iterator::chain(
    pairs.iter().map(|(a, _)| *a),
    pairs.iter().map(|(_, b)| *b).rev(),
).collect();

sort_by_indices(&mut cells, sort_indicies);
```

Then just follow the steps I outlined above to merge the cells:

```
for i in 0..cells.len()/2 {
    let cell_to_merge = cells.pop().unwrap();
    cells[i].hybrid(cell_to_merge);
}
```

And there we're done! Full code and demonstration output available [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=574a6ddfc676096ba10781a3058ae16b). You'll see it outputs the merged cells as described by `pairs`:

```
merging 1 with 5
merging 0 with 3
merging 4 with 2
```

---

> I have a vector of n cells, and among them I randomly pick k pairs (no resampling, of course), then for each pair, fuse the latter into the former, and eventually free the later

If this should be done *randomly* then we don't need to track the exact pairs we want to merge, we can just shuffle the array and do the last step only!

```
use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

cells.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());

for i in 0..cells.len()/2 {
    let cell_to_merge = cells.pop().unwrap();
    cells[i].hybrid(cell_to_merge);
}
```

Once again a demonstration is available [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a324ba9db8f7e72b561249db683cc5b) and an example output merged like so:

```
merging 5 with 0
merging 3 with 4
merging 2 with 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to implement that. The simplest is probably to use [`itertools`'s `tuples()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#tuples.chunks):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

let cells = cells
    .into_iter()
    .tuples()
    .map(|(mut a, b)| {
        a.hybrid(b);
        a
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    
println!("{:?}", cells);
```

Comment: And `array_chunks()` for people who are fine using unstable features.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `<[T]>::chunks()` can't work because we require owned values. But `array_chunks()` is fine.

Comment: @kmdreko Ah, I knew there was something I was missing!

Comment: Thanks @Chayim Friedman for the quick and elegant answer. My question in fact is a bit more complex—I have a vector of *n* cells, and among them I randomly pick *k* pairs (no resampling, of course), then for each pair, fuse the latter into the former, and eventually free the later. I wonder if there is more generic approach.

Comment: Instead of randomly picking you could shuffle the original vector and otherwise use the same algorithm, should be an equivalent result @foehn, otherwise you can always `.(swap_)remove` the pairs and add them again when all have been merged.

Comment: Good suggestion and thanks @cafce25. However, I still would like to hear more generic solution (e.g. using `std` and stable features only). I think my question boils downs into the best practice for such a task—given a vector input, select a subset of elements, modify some of them according to the "interaction" with the others, then free up the others. It would be great if someone could show me this way.

Comment: One generic method I can think of now, is to make `Cell` `Clone`-able, and change `fn hybrid` such that it takes in `cell: &Cell` and works on `cell.clone()`. This way, the ownership of `cells[1]`, `cells[3]` is no longer transferred and thereafter can be cleared by `cells.remove(1)`, `cells.remove(3)`. But I guess there are better solutions.

Comment: Artificialy limiting yourself to `std` only definitely isn't "best practice" or really feasible in most of Rust. I'd say this is the most idiomatic, stable solution, combined with a shuffle to get the random pairs you're after.

Comment: @foehn If you don't care about the order of the elements in the vector, you can `swap_remove()` the elements you want to merge into others.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Sven Marnach, the order doesn't matter.